# flow issue I can't overcome. Passing props buy not confirming to shape

Tags: flowtype

I have a parent component, this a very scaled down version.

I define type State (as example shows)..... and then I pass down a portion of (their values) them into a child component. That child component (in a seperate file) again, defines its props.... but I am getting errors for every single prop in the parent. infuriating.

for each prop being passed to the "MyChildComponent", I am getting this error:

**props of React element `MyChildComponent`. This type is incompatible with object type**

```
type State = {
   name: string,
   age: number,
   shoe: number,
   hair: string
}

class Dude extends component<void, Props, State> {
  props: Props;
  state: State;

  // these values get over-written by some ajax call
  constructor() {
     this.state = {
       name: 'george',
       age: 999,
       hair: 'brown',
       shoe: 11
     }

  displaySomeComponent = (): React.Element<*> => {
    const { name, age, hair } = this.state;
    return (
     // EACH ONE OF THESE GIVES AN ERROR
     //Flow: props of React element `MyChildComponent`. This type is incompatible with object type 
      <MyChildComponent
        name={name},
        age={age},
        hair={hair}
      />
    )

  }
}

// In a separate file for MyChildComponent
// No errors in this file
type Props = {
   name: string,
   age: number,
   hair: string
}
class MyChildComponent extends component<void, Props, void> {
   props: Props;

   render() {
    // all renders fine
   }
}
```

I am at my wits end. I do not understand what is going on, as I've passed things into many child components, but this is mucking up. I am thinking it might have something to do with the destructuring?

Comment: What version of Flow are you using? Looks like it's less then 0.53, but more specific might help.

Comment: I am using flow-bin: 0.52

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it's hard to say. If I fix a few syntax errors, this seems to work fine in Flow 0.54: [my version](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBLAtgB1gJwC6gFSgCGAzqAEoCmRAxnpFrKqAORbV0uKI4Ce6lUAGUcRHIIC8oAN6JQ8gHZFUlAFygSOLMgUBzADRz5RXWtAKArqgBGlLIfkaAFrDOWbdh-KdFkWdZraeogAvtw00KRkACIWACaClAAe4gpxZFS0OAB0AMJMmAqUCjgAPABusMhx+sKi4gB8MkaaYmYibQDc3PIgoDhOlCSC5UTQFkOgpniw5XYAtPDaOKmg1rwaTIJEAFZESaA0Y9BGNLAKgRZ02AAUAJTNjhoWAlj3Ro4DyCTZreKgUlkT0cShU6hYpmwphYXmBJjMAE4kbCnj4-ODrIx4AoYR8niQXGYAIxEvGgMJhIxxb7oSK8IRbfIYc7FPBSe7qTJ0bIAUWglBUJVK+CaEiaQMcZwueGk5mUlFq8NqaKw5IB-Sc31+9Uo3Se7BwFiwClANzJfR5AEFcgAJUAAeQAcjyHQAxUAAFRtPKELoA4gBJABqPtAlsdoB55HI9vI5uArrg8HU6EY6DIsEgFA4eEo-MFeAABgBZXi5TXQOJMwqswvZT2ash8ASgb6thRnDBiZDWfmgeDIAagWDWHaUOj9fiCMmgUql8vISvVlklGeKeUSaSgyhhYGOeGb+G7vegFWblXHp7ABp4u49cmhbjcPoBk1EDSUdBELBtUCQReCJA2CgPOFZVgUK44IgfSOrAoB2IwWBkDoGptv+-I8FOoAAAppiQABM6oSnKYIaFoOgGB88LqO4tj2B8KoBORwRhBEUQgWWYHLkUJTwSkxTpNmWR5BBPFlLhsDpvhtSVNU4ofKmkkkOoElSd0HzsGkdj3I8jh9McoCaQkSF-jolAfBSQA)

To track down what is wrong, you might try adding type declarations to see where things go wrong. Like, inside the parent render method, under the destructuring, try adding `name: string;` and see if Flow complains about that.